# Elegant way to prepend to a module which is already included?

Tags: ruby

I want to monkey-patch a gem and the targeted code is in a module.
Unfortunately, at the time when I'm prepending my patch, the module has already been included in various classes and the new code has no effect.

Example:

```rb
module Feature
  def action
    puts "Feature"
  end
end

module Patch
  def action
    puts "Patch"
  end
end

class Base1
  include Feature
end

Feature.prepend Patch

class Base2
  include Feature
end


Base1.new.action # Returns "Feature", I want it to be "Patch" instead.
Base2.new.action # Returns "Patch"
```

When I prepend to `Feature` before it is included into `Base2` the patch works, but with the real gem I cannot change the order.

Is there an elegant way to solve this or do I have to traverse `ObjectSpace` to find which classes already include the `Feature` module?

Comment: Well, what would a unit test look like for what your expectations are? Also is there any good reason you can't just fork the gem and monkey patch the source?

Comment: Updated the question, I want the `action` method to be the same for both classes. I don't want to fork the gem, because I don't want to regularly merge upstream changes into my fork. 20 additional code lines don't warrant the work, IMHO. Also it would be somewhat frustrating, because the "old" alias_method_chain has worked with minimal effort so far ☺

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR – you can't in general, but `Base1.include Patch` may be good enough.

---

For your example code, the [`ancestors`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Module.html#method-i-ancestors) of `Base1` and `Base2` are: (aligned for clarity)

```
Base1.ancestors #=> [Base1,        Feature, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
Base2.ancestors #=> [Base2, Patch, Feature, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

`Base2` has an additional ancestor `Patch` before `Feature` – the result of `Feature.prepend Patch`.

Ruby doesn't allow us to freely modify a module's ancestors chain, so we can't just prepend `Patch` to `Feature` retroactively.

But fortunately, `Patch` is the first module after the `Base` class, so we can resort to [`include`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Module.html#method-i-include) to append `Patch` to `Base1` instead:

```
Base1.include Patch
Base1.ancestors #=> [Base1, Patch, Feature, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Obviously, this only works for very specific cases and not in general.

Here's a counter example:

```
module Feature
  def action ; 'Feature' ; end
end

module Foo
  def action ; "#{super} overridden" ; end
end

module Patch
  def action ; 'Patch' ; end
end

class Base1
  include Feature
  include Foo
end

Feature.prepend(Patch)

class Base2
  include Feature
  include Foo
end

Base1.new.action #=> "Feature overridden"
Base2.new.action #=> "Patch overridden"

Base1.include Patch

Base1.new.action #=> "Patch"
```

Looking at the ancestors reveals the problem:

```
Base1.ancestors #=> [Base1, Foo,        Feature, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
Base2.ancestors #=> [Base2, Foo, Patch, Feature, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
Base1.include Patch
Base1.ancestors #=> [Base1, Patch, Foo, Feature, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

`Patch` and `Foo` are out of order.

Comment: It would be nice, if `ancestors.insert` worked... Thank you for dissecting the problem!

Comment: This is a good explanation of the problem, but it does not answer the question of whether there is a way (that does not necessary employ `include` or `prepend`) the OP can achieve the desired end result when `Feature` appears at an arbitrary location in classes' ancestor chains.  Even in the special case you mention at the beginning, where `Base1.include Patch` works, `ObjectSpace` would be needed to find those classes `c` for which `c.ancestors[1] == Feature` and the OP would prefer to not use `ObjectSpace`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland _"but it does not answer the question of whether there is a way [...] when Feature appears at an arbitrary location"_ – there's no way for the general case, just for special cases. Sorry if that was unclear.

Answer (score 0):

```
module Feature
  def action
    puts "Feature"
  end
end

class Base
  include Feature
end
```

After `include Feature` you're only option is to redefine the instance methods of `Feature` that are to be altered, at the place in the code where that is desired.

```
Feature.define_method(:action) { "Patch" }
# other methods follow

Base.new.action
  #=> "Patch"
```

Comment: `define_method` would work in my example, but if `Feature` was included in yet another module, like `Base <- Wrapper <- Feature <- Patch`, it would be recursively the same problem. I suspect that looking at the current inclusion chain via `ObjectSpace` would be the only generic solution. `Patch` needs to know where it is to be included besides its immediate ancestor...

Comment: I don't follow. If `Wrapper` preceded `Feature` in the ancestor chain and `Wrapper` contained an instance method `action`, that method would properly have precedence over `action` in `Feature` regardless of the latter had been replaced using `define_method`, so I don't understand why `Wrapper` is relevant.